# How can the table overlapping issue regarding SSRS HTML exports be solved?

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, reporting-services

I have been at this all day and I just can't figure out how to do it. This is the case:

I am using SQL Server 2012 with SQL Server Reporting Services to serve reports from an ASP.NET MVC 4-based application (C#). I can export to any desired format, except HTML 5, but I can export to HTML 4.0. This is where the problems come barging through the door. The rendering of an SSRS report in HTML 4 is not exactly exquisite, it works wonderfully in Opera and Internet Explorer, but it's a nightmare in Firefox and Chrome. The problem is that the HTML tables overlap as soon as you scroll down to where page 2 would have begun. From there on and until the end of the report the overlapping problem just increases exponentially.

I have thought about many possible solutions like manipulating the CSS or the HTML, which is next to impossible thanks to Microsoft creativity.

Does anyone at all have any experience with solving this problem? I'm at a complete and utter loss here.

Comment: I decided to go with an MVC/WebForms-affilition since Microsoft has announced that they do not support SSRS reports in anything but Internet Explorer. My solution is to use the ReportViewer control in WebForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with an MVC/WebForms-affilition since Microsoft has announced that they do not support SSRS reports in anything but Internet Explorer. My solution is to use the ReportViewer control in WebForms.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today and resolved it by setting KeepTogether=True in the tablix properties under general:

[image: tablix properties]